# How to connect AI Platform Training job to Cloud SQL PSQL DB?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-ml, gcp-ai-platform-training

I have a simple python program to connect to a PSQL DB on google cloud platform. When I run it locally it connects successfully (only if I manually tell the DB to allow my local IP address) to the DB via the host address (public IP), port, username, and password.

When I package this in a Docker image and run it locally, it connects successfully (only if I manually tell the DB to allow my local IP address).

Here is where it fails:
If I stop telling the DB to allow my local IP address, it fails.

Also, After I push my docker image to google cloud container registry.
Then use ai-platform training job to grab the container and do something via the code:

```
gcloud ai-platform jobs submit training $JOB_NAME   --region $REGION   --master-image-uri $IMAGE_URI  --   app.py --user_arg='Y'
```

I communicate with the image via flags and I am sure the image is responding properly. However, when I try to connect to the PSQL DB, I'm getting the error:

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection timed out.
Is the server running on host ... and accepting TCP/IP connections on port ...?
```

I do not want to use the cloud sql proxy to solve this problem, nor do I want to set any sort of static IP and manually "allow" it in the DB settings.

I want to facilitate the connection via the IAM server accounts. I gave all of the services the following permissions:
Cloud SQL Admin, Cloud SQL Editor, Cloud SQL Client, Cloud SQL Instance User, Cloud SQL Service Agent.

As you can tell, I gave the permissions to every account that I can, and it still isn't connecting. Any help would be appreciated!

Also, when I call gcloud ai-platform jobs submit training ... I know that some service account creates an instance to execute the job. I think it is this instance that can't connect. I've read so many gcloud docs already and I am baffled. Maybe I missed something obvious :(

Comment: It's almost certainly a matter of firewall rules. Review the ingress rules and check which IP addresses are allowed to access port 5432 of your DB.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'm looking into allowing http and https requests specifically to my service account but it's still not working. I also edited the question to more accurately reflect what works. (I made an error when I initially posted the problem)

Comment: In order to allow connections to your DB, you need to open port 5432, not HTTP(S)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run a job with AI Platform, you run it in serverless. Not in your project, but in Google side, somewhere but not in your project. Therefore, the created VM(s) aren't in your project (you don't see them into Compute Engine page) and thus not in your VPC.

So, to open the port 5432 is totally useless because it's not the same network. The only solution is to keep a public IP on your database (with no network authorized, only the public IP) and to use Cloud SQL proxy (even if you don't want).

*Of course, the other solution is to authorized the 0.0.0.0/0 network on the PSQL public IP, but it's absolutely not a good piece of advice!*

However, I have a remark: IMO it's not the right pattern to use directly the database in your training job. Indeed, in the training job, you need speed, efficiency and to reduce the latency. Using a database is not really great for this.

The correct pattern could be

- Prepare your data before (extract the data from your database, and save them into file (csv format for example))
- Store the file in a Regional bucket (not multi regional, if more efficient)
- Change your training job to use files instead of SQL query
- Run your training job in the same region as your regional bucket.

Comment: RE: Your first paragrah --> But isn't the "Google Cloud ML Engine Service Agent" responsible for executing the jobs? I assumed that if I gave this agent the right permissions, the jobs would be able to access the DB. 

RE: authorizing all IPs --> This works for now but I'll most likely use buckets similar to how you suggested. Whatever triggers the data entry would also trigger the ETL to get what I need in a bucket.

Comment: The service account service agent is loaded in the Google serverless world to access to your resources. You can access to Cloud SQL service (with Cloud SQL Proxy for example), but it doesn't route the network traffic to your VPC.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this feature: [Using VPC Network Peering with Training](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/vpc-peering)